# How to create PKPaymentButton in IB?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, applepay

The following code is from WWDC 2015 Session 702 **Apple Pay Within Apps - Emporium: A Simple Shopping Experience with Apple Pay**

```
    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks(ProductTableViewController.supportedNetworks) {

        let button = PKPaymentButton(type: .Buy, style: .Black)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProductTableViewController.applePayButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        button.center = applePayView.center
        button.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleRightMargin]
        applePayView.addSubview(button)
    }
```

I wonder if we could create this button in IB.

Comment: just add your button to sub class of PKPaymentButton

Comment: What about the previous versions that support apple pay, but not this button ? Meaning how would you initialize a button in xib that conditionally subclasses to PKPaymentButton ?

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for this as well and it turns out it is possible to use IB to set this.
Just create a UIButton in IB, set its type to PKPaymentButton and now in the UserDefinedRuntimeAttributes set "style" and "type" as wanted, corresponding to PKPaymentButtonStyle and PKPaymentButtonType.
For example:

```
type = 1 //corresponding to - PKPaymentButtonTypeBuy
style = 2 //corresponding to - PKPaymentButtonStyleBlack
```

[image: Example Setup]

And this is what you end up getting:

[image: Example Button]

PS. Interestingly, you can set cornerRadius in the IB Attributes, but as you can see it doesn't affect the button. It seems that even setting it in code doesn't do anything. So if you don't want to be stuck with a rectangular PKPaymentButton - just put it in a view, whose corners you round and make sure you tick `Clip to Bounds` in IB (or in code `yourButtonHolder.clipsToBounds = true` )

Comment: Don't forget to add PassKit.framework to your project's Build Phases --> Link Binary With Libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the class of the button in the Identity Inspector in Interface Builder, by editing the Custom Class field.  The outlet you create for it at that point should be of type PKPaymentButton.

Comment: How do you set the PKPaymentButtonStyle in IB?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this @chrish

Comment: This is not the best way to go. You won't be able to change button type or style. And the default button's look is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can set and style and button type can be achieved using below lines of code.

applePayButton.setValue(paymentButtonStyle.rawValue, forKey: "style")
applePayButton.setValue(2, forKey: "type")